# widget in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

like other mobile, is it possible to create widget with miultipleviewcontroller (with their views) in iphone sdk?

Comment: if we select middle button of mouse , calculator,calendar,clock will come,we can handle individually...

Answer (score 0):

"Widget" is one of those words that is so general as to be meaningless. If you can be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, we'll try to help.

When my clients say "widget", what they mean is "You should charge me less money for this than if I used the word 'application'."

Comment: if we select middle button of mouse , calculator,calendar,clock will come,we can handle individually in MAC machine..please see my above comments